# c# convert string to array on char(253) deliminator

Tags: c#, universe

Not entirely sure the following code is going to help many people, but here goes

```
          try
        {
            uvConnect = UniObjects.OpenSession(serverId, sUser, sPass, sAcct, "uvcs");

            // Open Movie File
            UniFile uvFile = uvConnect.CreateUniFile("MOVIES");
            UniDynArray movieRec = uvFile.Read(txtMovieId.Text);

            string sMovieData = movieRec.StringValue;
            MessageBox.Show(sMovieData);
        }
```

sMovieData contains a single string of the entire record retrieve from MOVIES file, each field is deliminated by a char(253) character in the database I am using.

Is there a function/method/etc to convert the string to an array using char(253) as a value deliminator

Comment: I think you want to use the [String.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/how-to/parse-strings-using-split) method.

Comment: I know this is closed, but if you are reading the whole record into Dynamic Array (which is an associative array[X][X]) and a record has more than one attribute Char(254) your output is not going to be as you expect. You could end up with a string array that start off with movies with the last movie joined with an CHAR(254) to the first director, followed by director elements until you get the last one of those and then you get an element that is the director and the year of release joined by a CHAR(254) and so on and so forth. Use  UniDynArray.Extract() to get the Attribute you want first.

Comment: Hey Van, actually found an old IBM uonet developers guide which went through the UniDynArray with some decent examples, so now happily using that approach. But still good to get additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
string[] fields = sMovieData.Split((char)253);
```

Comment: Thanks Jamie and Donnie working like a brought one

Answer (score 1):

Try this... `string[] arrayValues = "stringToConvertToArray".Split((char)253);`